# SvelteKit Docker fetch issue

Tags: fastapi, sveltekit

I have searched for many hours but haven't found any answer to this problem:
I have 2 docker containers. One with FastAPI backend and one with Sveltekit app.

[Containers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2MeH.png)

Sending requests with openapi docs is fine. Sveltekit with npm run dev works fine too. But SvelteKit fetch in docker container throws error:

```
frontend  | TypeError: fetch failed
frontend  |     at node:internal/deps/undici/undici:12443:11
frontend  |     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
frontend  |     at async resolve2 (file:///app/build/server/index.js:4118:14)
frontend  |     at async respond (file:///app/build/server/index.js:3941:22)
frontend  |     at async fetch (file:///app/build/server/index.js:3696:26) {
frontend  |   cause: Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established   
frontend  |       at TLSSocket.onConnectEnd (node:_tls_wrap:1727:19)
frontend  |       at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:531:35)
frontend  |       at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1696:12)
frontend  |       at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
frontend  |     code: 'ECONNRESET',
frontend  |     path: undefined,
frontend  |     host: '192.168.0.13',
frontend  |     port: 443,
frontend  |     localAddress: null
frontend  |   }
frontend  | }
```

### My vite config

```
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [sveltekit()],

    server: {
        host: true,
        proxy: {
            '/api': {
                target: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000', // see here
                changeOrigin: true,
                secure: false,
                rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/api/, '')
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Tried changing target to http://localhost:8000 and http://backend:8000 but nothing helped.

### Frontend Dockerfile

```
FROM node:latest AS builder

RUN mkdir /app && mkdir /app/data

COPY . /app

RUN cd /app && yarn install && \
    yarn build 



FROM node:latest

RUN mkdir /app

COPY --from=builder /app/build /app/build
COPY --from=builder /app/package.json /app/yarn.lock /app/

RUN cd /app && \ 
    yarn install --production && \
    yarn cache clean

WORKDIR /app

CMD ["node", "build/index.js"]
```

### Docker compose

```
services:
  api:
    build:
      context: ./backend
      target: builder
    container_name: backend
    environment:
      - PORT=8000
      - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_HOST=${POSTGRES_HOST}
      - POSTGRES_PORT=${POSTGRES_PORT}
      - POSTGRES_NAME=${POSTGRES_NAME}
      - POSTGRES_DB_URL=${POSTGRES_DB_URL}
      - POSTGRES_ECHO=${POSTGRES_ECHO}

      - EMAIL_USERNAME=${EMAIL_USERNAME}
      - EMAIL_PASSWORD=${EMAIL_PASSWORD}
      - EMAIL_FROM=${EMAIL_FROM}
      - EMAIL_PORT=${EMAIL_PORT}
      - EMAIL_HOST=${EMAIL_HOST}
      - EMAIL_STARTTLS=${EMAIL_STARTTLS}
      - EMAIL_SSL_TLS=${EMAIL_SSL_TLS}
      - USE_CREDENTIALS=${USE_CREDENTIALS}
      - VALIDATE_CERTS=${VALIDATE_CERTS}

      - REDIS_HOST=redis
      - REDIS_PORT=${REDIS_PORT}
      - REDIS_DB=${REDIS_DB}

      - OAUTH_SECRET_KEY=${OAUTH_SECRET_KEY}
      - OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRE_MINUTES=${OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRE_MINUTES}
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    expose:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis
  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./frontend
    container_name: frontend
    expose:
      - "80:3000"
    ports:
      - "80:3000"
  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_NAME}
      - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
    expose:
      - 5432
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  redis:
    image: redis
    ports:
      - "6380:6379"
    expose:
      - "6379"
    volumes:
      - redis_data:/data
  worker:
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: Celerybuild

    environment:
      - PORT=8000
      - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_HOST=${POSTGRES_HOST}
      - POSTGRES_PORT=${POSTGRES_PORT}
      - POSTGRES_NAME=${POSTGRES_NAME}
      - POSTGRES_DB_URL=${POSTGRES_DB_URL}
      - POSTGRES_ECHO=${POSTGRES_ECHO}

      - EMAIL_USERNAME=${EMAIL_USERNAME}
      - EMAIL_PASSWORD=${EMAIL_PASSWORD}
      - EMAIL_FROM=${EMAIL_FROM}
      - EMAIL_PORT=${EMAIL_PORT}
      - EMAIL_HOST=${EMAIL_HOST}
      - EMAIL_STARTTLS=${EMAIL_STARTTLS}
      - EMAIL_SSL_TLS=${EMAIL_SSL_TLS}
      - USE_CREDENTIALS=${USE_CREDENTIALS}
      - VALIDATE_CERTS=${VALIDATE_CERTS}

      - REDIS_HOST=redis
      - REDIS_PORT=${REDIS_PORT}
      - REDIS_DB=${REDIS_DB}

      - OAUTH_SECRET_KEY=${OAUTH_SECRET_KEY}
      - OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRE_MINUTES=${OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRE_MINUTES}
    depends_on:
      - redis
  flower:
    image: mher/flower:0.9.7
    command: ["flower", "--broker=redis://redis:6379", "--port=5555"]
    expose:
      - 5555
    depends_on:
      - redis
volumes:
  postgres_data:
  redis_data:
```

Comment: How are you running your containers? Do you use docker compose? Do you use the network parameter when creating your containers allowing them to see each other? What does `backend` refer to?

Comment: Hi, I'm running containers with docker compose. I don't use network parameter. I expose ports manually using PORTS in docker compose. Backend is the name of container running FastAPI.

Comment: Add your compose file to the question and verify that the request is happening towards `http://backend` (without https)

Comment: Added docker compose

Comment: Nothing in your docker compose is named `backend`, so `http://backend` won't resolve to anything. Did you mean `api`? The service name is the important part.

Comment: Changed to ```target: http://api:8000```, but still facing the same error

Comment: Since the error message references TLS; are you (or SvelteKit) making an https request against a http endpoint?

Comment: If I understand correctly I disabled tls with: `process.env['NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED'] = 0;` So I am making http requests. However `frontend  |     port: 443,` is https port isn't it?

Comment: No, that just disables verifying the certificates presented on an https connection. Regardless, your error message is about port 443, but you said you've configured it to use `http://api:8000`  - so the error message is using a different port than what you've configured, and it tries to access this on http. Are you sure this error message is related to accessing your backend? And that's actually using the URL you've configured?

Comment: I am pretty sure that this error comes from fetching my backend. I believe SvelteKit is blocking fetch. When I use `curl -XGET http://api:8000/conferences/` from frontend docker container it works just fine. 
`api       | INFO:     172.19.0.3:36468 - "GET /conferences/ HTTP/1.1" 200 OK`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this to hooks.server.js and it worked:
[reference](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/hooks#server-hooks-handlefetch)

```
import { backend_url } from './utils';

export async function handleFetch({ request, fetch }) {
    request = new Request(`http://api:8000${request.url.split(backend_url)[1]}`, request);
    return fetch(request);
}
```

Where api is name of docker container